# POST request with no page refreshing in Yesod

Tags: ajax, post, yesod, page-refresh, yesod-forms

The task is to create a registration form with pretty error handling.
I'm a newbie in Yesod, so the only way I found to do this is:

```
regForm :: Form User

getRegRExtra extraFormWidget = do
  (formWidget, enctype) <- case extraFormWidget of
                             Nothing -> generateFormPost regForm
                             Just val -> return val
  defaultLayout $ $(widgetFile "reg/reg")

getRegR = getRegRExtra Nothing

postRegR = do
  ((result, widget), enctype) <- runFormPostNoToken regForm 
  case result of
    FormSuccess person -> undefined
    _ -> getRegRExtra (Just (widget, enctype))
```

But there is a problem: Page refreshes on every submit while I want it to do this dynamically.
I know it could be fixed with the help of Ajax or Jquery,
but I'll lose all the benefits I get while using Yesod POST functions.
Is there any standard way to deal with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
-- Used for returning plain html as AJAX response.
noLayout :: Widget -> Handler Html
noLayout widget = do
  pc <- widgetToPageContent widget
  withUrlRenderer [hamlet| ^{pageBody pc} |]

-- Replace a default event handler with the AJAX one.
getRegR :: Handler Html
getRegR = do
  ((res, formWidget), enctype) <- runFormPost regForm
  defaultLayout $ do
    $(widgetFile "reg/reg")
    addScriptRemote "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"
    toWidget [julius|
      $(document).on('click', '.btn-important', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url:'@{RegR}',
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'html',
          data:$('#form-reg').serialize(),
          success: function(data) { $('#form-reg').html(data); }
        });
      }); |]

postRegR :: Handler Html
postRegR = do
  ((result, widget), enctype) <- runFormPostNoToken regForm
  noLayout widget
```